# Visual Studio hangs after Xamarin.Android build

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have updated today my xamarin (SDK, Nuget Packages ecc..) at the latest version.

I need to compile my solution using Multi-Dex because Google Play Services was updated ad I found too many references issue.

After that update and after a night spent I don't understand why Visual Studio hangs after build succeded.
It Hangs and return responsive after about 5 minutes.

Also if I deploy directly on my android device, visual studio, build with success, deploy on device with success and then... hangs. It hangs for 5 minutes and then the debug on device started fine.

I'm frustating. Has anybody encuntered the same problem?

In the solution I have many projects (UWP, web ecc..) and these projects build fine without hangs.
Only when i build android, visual studio hangs.

Thanks for any suggestion...

Comment: We will need more information such as a diagnostic build output. You can learn more about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523414/slow-app-build-xamarin-for-visual-studio/40615665#40615665